# No more Ctrl + Tab to those who emulate numpads?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

[image]

I saw a post earlier and I can't post an answer because my reputation is not high enough so I made this.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I saw some questions about having the 2.8 blender changed the Ctrl + tab shortcuts that gave a problem to those who use emulate Numpad just like me. All I did to solve this problem is to make a new shortcut, because why not?. I can't comment my answer to this question because my reputation is not high enough to do so. I hope this helps and to those who post the question earlier, I hope they found this.

Comment: If nobody has an answer to it and you come up with a solution to your problem, feel free to post it here as an answer. No need to use the comments for that.